# Calling Powershell function from another power shell script works with error prompt

Tags: function, powershell, scripting

Hi all I have the following script that calls another script which sends an email.The first script is :

```
#check status of scheduler
function Check_Scheduler{param([int]$filename) 
if($filename -eq 33)
{
  $Scheduler="Process_F33"
}
elseif($filename -eq 07)
{
 $Scheduler="Process_F07"
 }
$status=(Get-ScheduledTask | Where TaskName -EQ $Scheduler).State 
#read from a text file
$startTime=(Get-Content -Path E:\AshimTest\time.txt) 
$endTime = Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss
#calculate time difference
$TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan $startTime $endTime
if ($TimeDiff.Hours -lt 0) {
   $Hrs = ($TimeDiff.Hours) + 23
   $Mins = ($TimeDiff.Minutes) + 59
   $Secs = ($TimeDiff.Seconds) + 59 }
else {
$Hrs = $TimeDiff.Hours
$Mins = $TimeDiff.Minutes
$Secs = $TimeDiff.Seconds }
$Difference = '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $Hrs,$Mins,$Secs

if($status -eq "Running")
{
    if ($Hrs -gt 2)
     {
        #Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Scheduler
        echo "Sending email"
         . .E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1; Send-Mail -group "IT" -bodypath 
"E:\AshimTest\Body.txt" -subject "$Scheduler scheduler Process Failed"
      }
}

}
```

Everything runs fine, I get the email send as well but when I run it from powershell ISE i get following error, even though the script works fine and does what it has to do.

```
. : The term '.E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1' is not recognized as the name of 
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At E:\AshimTest\Check_Status.ps1:35 char:16
+              . .E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1; Send-Mail -group "IT" -
bodypath "E: ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: 
(.E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I get this error in powershell ISE but still the scripts work fine, do I need to worry or is there something wrong that I am not picking.I am beginner to PowerShell.

Comment: Removing the leading period in ".E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1"

Comment: still get the error but scripts work fine as expected.The error is still there

Comment: What is the contents and purpose of the `GroupEmail.ps1` file?

Comment: Are you dot sourcing the E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1 to load a function into memory? If so . E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1 should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
. .E:\AshimTest\GroupEmail.ps1
```

To

```
. .\GroupEmail.ps1
```

Make sure both scripts are in the same folder.

Comment: That's weird. I'm not sure why you're getting the error. But . Sourcing scripts is a supported and recommend practice to reduce code copying across scripts. For now I would ignore the error.

I recommend you look at Visual Studio Code as a code editor for PowerShell instead of the ISE.